# when I add a title and a subtitle to my svg they get above my graphic

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I basically have a barchart, and I want to put 2 texts.  I want to put a title at a distance from my graph (top 30px for example). and I want to put a subtitle at a distance from the graph, so that it is located in the bottom right (bottom 30px for example)

[image]

No matter what method I use, my texts are always above my graphic, I wish I had separation margins between graphic and texts.

Desired effect:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

this is my live code:

https://plnkr.co/edit/mRjyYN9nWiMWYRzj7Gtf?p=preview

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


//set title
svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", (width / 2))
  .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "18px")
  .text("title");


//set bottom-right text

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 960 - 80)
  .attr("y", 500 - 30)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .style("font-size", "14px")
  .text("subtitle");
```

current problem using your code (user lemming):

[image]

Comment: "I want to put 2 texts. one above my graph without it being above the graph". Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @BrettGregson Sorry, my native language is Spanish. I want to put a title at a distance from my graph (top 30px for example). and I want to put a subtitle at a distance from the graph, so that it is located in the lower right (bottom 30px for example).

Comment: The `y` axis is out the top because you are assigning a negative value to the text's y value: 0 - (margin.top / 2). In order to get it into the frame, the y value needs to be positive. Try 0 + (margin.top / 2).

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/yLtkdsk7gPDrgxjDl7cS?p=preview

Comment: @lemming thanks, but it not works for me... same problem, there is not space between title and the graph, and subtitle and graph

Comment: Did you click on my plnkr above?

Comment: plnkr.co/edit/yLtkdsk7gPDrgxjDl7cS?p=preview  yes! is that

Answer (score 0):

Normally you subtract the margins from the dimension of the div you are rendering to, like this, assuming the div is 800 x 600

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: @lemming has fixed it in your plunk

Comment: that is not solution to my problem :(